# How to update a ManyToMany relationship in Objection JS?

Tags: objection.js

I am learning Objection JS. I have a manyToMany relationship on an accounts and roles table that are related through an accounts_roles table. I was wondering if there was a way to update account roles on the account model by doing something like:

`AccountOne.addRoles([roleId])`

`AccountOne.removeRoles([roleId])`

`AccountOne.updateRoles([roleId])`

`AccountOne.deleteRoles([roleId])`

I searched online and went through the official objection documentation. So far I can do a GraphInsert, on my account model with a role object "x", and that creates a new role "x" with a relationship correctly defined in accounts_roles. But that always creates a new role. I would like to add and remove relationships between existing accounts and roles. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This quested was answered by koskimas on git hub 

"Yep, you can use the relate and unrelate methods."

Answer (score 6):

You can use [relate](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#relate) and [unrelate](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/mutate-methods.html#unrelate) to connect two rows together in a many-to-many relationship. Obviously, for this to work, you have to have your Models' `relationMappings` set up correctly. I have put a pair of example models too. It's critical that you match your key of your `relationMappings` to what you put in your `$relatedQuery` method to call `relate`/`unrelate` on.

#### Example Models

```
//Person and Movie Models
const { Model } = require('objection');

class Person extends Model {
  static tableName = 'persons';

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      movies: {
        relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: Movie,
        join: {
          from: 'persons.id',
          through: {
            from: 'persons_movies.person_id',
            to: 'persons_movies.movie_id'
          },
          to: 'movies.id'
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

class Movie extends Model {
  static tableName = 'movies';

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      persons: {
        relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: Person,
        join: {
          from: 'movies.id',
          through: {
            from: 'persons_movies.movie_id',
            to: 'persons_movies.person_id'
          },
          to: 'persons.id'
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

#### Relate Example

> In the case of a many-to-many relation, creates a join row to the join table.

```
const person = await Person
  .query()
  .findById(123);

const numRelatedRows = await person
  .$relatedQuery('movies')
  .relate(50);

// movie with ID 50 is now related to person with ID 123
// this happened by creating a new row in the linking table for Movies <--> Person
```

#### Unrelate Example

> For ManyToMany relations this deletes the join row from the join table.

```
const person = await Person
  .query()
  .findById(123)

const numUnrelatedRows = await person
  .$relatedQuery('movies')
  .unrelate()
  .where('id', 50);

// movie with ID 50 is now unrelated to person with ID 123
// this happened by delete an existing row in the linking table for Movies <--> Person
```